# Maximum update depth exceeded when trying to setState when user clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to When user clicks on list set a state

I have listing in li tag in a loop when user click one of li tag i want to update some state but react throws error.

Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested

Here my main piece of code:

```
class Header extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.showCatDetail=this.showCatDetail.bind(this);
    this.state={
        category:[],
        clk_category:[],
        detail:false
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/portfolio/create_category/')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(categoryJson => this.setState({category: categoryJson},()=>{
            this.sortCategory()
        }))
}

showCatDetail=(e)=>{

    e.preventDefault();


    this.setState({detail:true,clk_category:JSON.parse(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-item'))},()=>{
        console.log(this.state.clk_category)
    });


};


sortCategory = ()=>{

    let sortArray=this.state.category;
    let swap;

    for (let i=0;i<sortArray.length;i++)
    {
        for (let j=0;j<sortArray.length;j++){

            if(sortArray[i].category_rank>sortArray[j].category_rank){
                swap=sortArray[i];
                sortArray[i]= sortArray[j];
                sortArray[j]=swap;
            }
        }

    }

    this.setState({category:sortArray})

};

render(){

    let hreflink=null;
    let redirect=null;

    if (this.state.detail){
        redirect=<Redirect to={`/category_project/${this.state.clk_category.id}`}/>
    }

    return(
        <div>
            {redirect}
            <header id="header">
                <div id="trueHeader">
                    <div className="wrapper">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="logo">
                                <a href={hreflink} id="logo">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="menu_main">
                                <div className="navbar yamm navbar-default">
                                    <div className="container">
                                        <div className="navbar-header">
                                            <div className="visibledevice">
                                                <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                                                    <li><a href={hreflink} className="active">
                                                        <i className="fa fa-home">
                                                        </i> Home</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">
                                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                                                <li><a href={hreflink} className="active">
                                                    <i className="fa fa-home">
                                                    </i> Contact Us</a></li>
                                                {this.state.category.map(cat=>{
                                                    return(
                                                        <li data-item={JSON.stringify(cat)} onClick={(e)=>this.showCatDetail(e)}><a href={hreflink} >
                                                            <i className="fa fa-home">
                                                            </i>{cat.category_name}</a></li>
                                                    )
                                                })}
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

I can't figure out what the problem is...

Comment: are you using componentDidUpdate() at all?

Comment: yes I am using componentDidUpdate

Comment: Can you show us the code there? I'm pretty sure that's the problem. If you have logic in their that checks if this.state.detail is true, then it will just keep running which leads to your maximum depth error.

Comment: Do not use setState twice, put them in single

Comment: I am using componentDidMount, mistakenly I have mentioned  above componentDidUpdate in a comment.

Comment: show complete code please

Comment: @MUHAMMADNABEELL1F14BSCS0108 I think we need to see a bit more of your code before we can come up with an answer. As is, there doesnt appear to be anything you've shown us that would lead to the error you mentioned.

Comment: You know what, I am stumped. I'm not sure what could possibly be causing this error o_o

Comment: It is working for me

Answer (score -1):

onClick={(e)=>{this.showCatDetail(e)}}

Try this in onclick

Comment: componentDidMount{
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/portfolio/create_category/')
            .then(response=>response.json())
            .then(categoryJson => this.setState({category: categoryJson}))                              
    
    this.state.category.length > 0 && this.sortCategory();
    }